# Matplotlib savefig to BytesIO is slightly wrong?

Tags: c#, python, matplotlib

I'm trying to save [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) figures to a memory stream, exactly as in another example on SO:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io


plt.figure()
plt.plot([1, 2])
plt.title("test")
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format = 'png')
plt.savefig("real.png", format = 'png')
buf.seek(0)
data = buf.read()
buf.close()
f = open('copy.png', 'w')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

I find that copy.png is slightly larger in size and applications refuse to open it. Is this some sort of encoding issue?

**Background**:

I'm trying to use python.net to render graphs with matplotlib and pass them out to C# for drawing. I want to avoid writing the images to disk. Ideally, I want to write to some sort of byte array that I can work with in C#.

Comment: Works for me (1.2.0). What version of mpl do you have?

Comment: Thanks for checking. I'm running 1.1.0 which was the latest prebuilt I found for windows. I'll see if I can get 1.2.0 and test with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening the file in binary mode.

`f = open('copy.png', 'wb')`

From the documentation:

> Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files;
>   the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered
>   slightly when data is read or written. This behind-the-scenes
>   modification to file data is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll
>   corrupt binary data like that in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to
>   use binary mode when reading and writing such files.